# Apex trigger to update picklist on custom object from an activated order

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

I'm trying to write a trigger so that when an Order (standard object) is Activated, the Status__c picklist (custom field) on the HD__c (custom object connected to an OrderItem (standard object)) will be updated to a specific value.

Here's what i have so far, i know its missing a lot:

```
trigger ordertoupdate on Order (after update) {

List<HD__c> toUpdate = new list<HD__c>();

for(Order o : Trigger.New) {     

  // compare new and prev picklist values to create a list of Object__2 records to update

  if(AND(o.Status = 'Activated',o.Type LIKE 'Hard Drive%')) {

     HD__c toUp = new HD__c(Id = o.Id, Status__c = 'At Account' ); 

     toUpdate.add(toUp);

  } // end of if statement

} // end of for loop

if(toUpdate.isEmpty() == false) Update toUpdate;

} // end of trigger
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, this is a good first question on the site, thanks for providing what you're done so far and your complete requirements. So the HD__c objects that you want to update will already exist, right? Unless I'm misunderstanding your requirement, you probably don't need to declare new records of HD__c. We can use SOQL to retrieve the existing associated HD__c and update those. Also, this would typically be a before update trigger - any specific reason you need to use after update?

Comment: Thank you Brian.  You are correct, the records will already exist. I figured it needed to be after an update to the Order object changing the status of the order to Activated.  Is it better done otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I guessed at the ID field on HD__c and replaced your fuzzy string logic for "Hard Drive" with contains.

```
trigger updateHDsFromOrder on Order (after update) {
    Set<ID> ids = new Set<ID>();

    for (Order o : Trigger.new) {     
        if ((o.Status = 'Activated') && (o.Type.contains('Hard Drive'))) {
            ids.add(o.Id);
      } 
    } 

    List<HD__c> matchingHDs = [SELECT Status__c, OrderID__c FROM HD__c WHERE OrderID__c IN :ids];

    for (HD__c h : matchingHDs) {
        h.Status__c = 'At Account';
    }

    update matchingHDs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  The only missing piece i see is that the Order ID doesn't exist in the HD__c object, but rather the OrderItem contains the HD__c Id (OrderItem.HD__c) and the OrderItem contains the Order ID (OrderItem.OrderId), so the OrderItem object needs to be included somewhere to link HD to Order.